# Making the Blender Grid round

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to make the grid on blender round, like half a circle or similar. I'm trying to see how the magnetic fields will interact on a curve versus a flat surface. I wasn't sure how to do so, or if I was able to after already putting materials onto the existing grid. Help!

Comment: There is no way to alter the grid on the viewport or put materias since is not an object. Create a grid object and deform it to your needs. Please [edit] your question and show a reference image of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't have an image to reference, just wanted to see how the fields would be altered. How could I alternatively put the planes and forces on a half circle type object?

Comment: Easiest way of doing what you want is to add a curve object, convert it to a mesh (ALT+C) and select snap to vertices. This way you can snap your objects to a curve. You can also use a cylinder, which is faster, but leaves a bigger object.

Comment: @freemox When I select ALT+C I only get Curve from Mesh/Text and Mesh From curve/meta/surf/text as options. Not sure if I added the correct curve object or not have a personal preference on that I need

Comment: Select the 2nd option, Mesh from curve/meta/surf/text

Comment: How would you snap the objects together. I am currently using a cylinder and nothing changes after selecting Mesh from curve/meta/surf/text. I am currently in blender render but that doesn't matter too much for my existing work. I just added the cylinder, then ALT+C, then selected Mesh from curve/meta/surf/text, and then nothing changes

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to change the grid pattern in Blender. A workaround to this would be to add a circle curve to guide you.

[image]

This process will convert the circle curve to a mesh, meaning it will have vertices like a normal mesh would, as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

From there you can enable vert snapping to align your object to the circle:
[image]

As you notice, not all the spheres will align with the center on the vertices, to change this, you have to change the "nearest" option to "center" like so:
[image]

**Edit**
Asker requested this as a half-circle. This is easily achieved by simply cutting the circle in half.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it like a semi circle?

Comment: Updated my answer